# What are the differences between these ways to hide sections in an HTML document?

Tags: css, html

I found many different ways to hide part of my DOM inside my HTML document. Although I couldn't find a clear explanation for the differences between those ways to hide code.

Two ways by using CSS with: "`visibility: hidden;`" and "`display: none;`". Other two options were in the HTML doc itself: using "`hidden`" or "`aria-hidden`".

What is exactly the difference between these 4 options? Are they all hiding the code 'in the same way'?

Comment: What ***code*** are you hiding? Are you trying to hide executed JavaScript? Some Java code that you've included in the page as a demo? Who are you trying to hide it from? Why are you trying to hide it? - note that ***none*** of them actually hide the code. They just make it not display on the *rendered* page on browsers that support CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp

`display:none;`: the element will be hidden, and the page will be displayed as if the element is not there.

`visibility:hidden;` also hides an element. However, the element will still take up the same space as before.

As far as I know, `hidden` does the same as `display:none`, it's just a HTML5 shortcut. Note that it's not available in IE < 11.

`aria-hidden` does not hide at all. It acts as a hint for people with disabilities. In supporting browsers in conjunction with supporting assistive technology the content is not conveyed to the user via the assistive technology (screen readers and such).

Comment: One other interesting thing with `visibility: hidden` is that you can make a child of this element visible with `visibility: visible`. You can't do that with `display: none`, or `opacity: 0`.


Also note that you **can't** get the size of an element which is `display: none` in javascript.  
If you need to, try adding `position: absolute` to `visibility: hidden`;